# Fade out Columns in HTML-Table with jQuery: Why is .fadeTo() so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade out all cells in a column of my HTML-table when I click on a button in the Header of this col. For that I run the following JavaScript:

```
...
myDOMElement.find(".headerIcon").bind("click", function(event){
    var colo = $(event.target).parent().attr("id"); // colNo is stored as Icons id
    myDOMElement.find(".myTable").find("tr").find("#"+colo) // each tr has an id according to its colNumber 
        .each(function(index) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0,0.2);
        }
    });
});
```

This works as desired but is relative slow even on tables with only 200 rows.

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

Comment: You can do something like ` $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);

Comment: This is not faster than .fadeTo(0, 1); since the first argument is the Speed in milisecs (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeto.asp))

Answer (score 1):

`"#"+colo` is (must be!) a unique id. No reason for the cascaded finds - and if not, you are facing other problems:

```
...
myDOMElement.find(".headerIcon").bind("click", function(event){
    var colo = $(event.target).parent().attr("id"); // colNo is stored as Icons id
    $("#"+colo).fadeTo(0,0.2);
    });
});
```

**[edit]**

As per the comments, in order to fade out Columns, the id must better hold information about row and column and will thus be unique per cell:

```
  <tr>
     <td id="1.1">scheme is <col>.<row></td>
     <td id="2.1">
  ...

  <tr>
     <td id="1.2">
     <td id="2.2">
  ...

...
myDOMElement.find(".headerIcon").bind("click", function(event){
    var roco= $(event.target).parent().attr("id");
    var col = roco.split('.')[0];
    var row =  roco.split('.')[1];

    // now search all TD#s which have the clicked col (1.~) as a beginning of their ID
    myDOMElement.find("td[id^='" + col + ".']").each(function(index) {

           this.fadeTo(0,0.2);

    });
});
```

see also [jQuery Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Thanks. But this will not fade out the complete column, only the cell i clicked on.

Comment: Some modification made it work that way, but still slowly: `myDOMElement.find(".myTable").find("tr").find("#"+colo).fadeTo(0,0.2);`

Comment: __// each tr has an id according to its colNumber__ -show your generated html, please

Comment: if `myDOMElement.find(".myTable").find("tr").find("#"+colo)` is finding more than one element, `#<colno>` obviously is not unique. Side effects apply.

Comment: it cant be unique since I want to fade out each cell in this col and I have to address them in some way. But you are right: one should better use class Attribute instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont need the animation provided by .fadeOut() I fond a faster way to do this:

```
myDOMElement.find(".myTable").find("tr").find("#"+colo).css({opacity:0.2});
```